# How does an STL algorithm identify the container?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, iterator, containers

How does an STL algorithm identify on what kind of container it is operating on?
For example, `sort` accepts iterators as arguments.
How does it know what kind of container it has to sort?

Comment: Your second question should really be asked in a separate thread.

Comment: The answers below assume you already know how templates and (the basics of) template argument deduction work, but it seems you don't.  Basically, `sort()` is not a particular function but a *template* -- something that can be used to generate an (infinite) number of functions, automatically, by substituting in certain things (like container or iterator types) at *compile time*.  Ask if you want more info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't :-) That's the whole point of iterators -- the algorithms that work on them don't need to know anything about the underlying container, and vice versa.

How does it work then? Well, the iterators themselves have a certain set of [well-known properties](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/). For example, 'random-access' iterators allow any algorithm to access an element offset from iterator by a constant:

```
std::vector<int> vec = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
assert(*(vec.begin() + 2) == 3);
```

For a sort, the iterators need to support random access (in order to access all the elements between the first and end iterators in an arbitrary order), and they need to be writable (in order to assign or otherwise swap values around), otherwise known as 'output' iterators.

Example of an output iterator vs. an input (read-only) one:

```
std::vector<int> vec = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
*vec.begin() = 9;
assert(vec[0] == 9);

*vec.cbegin() = 10;    // Does not compile -- cbegin() yields a const iterator
                       // that is 'random-access', but not 'output'
```

Comment: Based on the type of iterator, how does sort happen?

Comment: I have added one more associated question.

Comment: @cppcoder: `std::swap()` swaps two arbitrary things (it's templated for the general case, and specialized for certain types for speed). `std::vector::swap` only swaps one vector's contents with another vector's contents.

Comment: @cppcoder In case ti wasn't clear, the vector's swap is an extremely efficient O(1) operation.

Comment: @Cameron Why does `std::vector::swap` exist when there is `std::swap`? What advantage does it offer?

Comment: @cppcoder: Good question. I don't know the reason why `std::vector::swap` exists separately, but it does make sense that the swap implementation is part of the vector implementation. `std::swap` just calls `std::vector::swap` for vectors anyway :-)

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't need to know the type of the container, it just needs to know the type of iterator.

Comment: I wouldn't say that the algorithm needs to know the type of iterator either. The *compiler* needs to know the type of the iterator, in order to make the template into a real function (because C++ is statically typed), but the algorithm itself doesn't care. It just blindly assumes that the iterator supports the operations it needs, and if it doesn't, you get compiler errors.

Comment: @Benjamin: Well yeah, but if the algorithm won't compile unless you give it a certain type of iterator, then I'd argue that that implicit assumption/coupling is strong enough to qualify as "caring" about the iterator's type :-)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned earlier, STL uses iterators, not containers. It uses the technique known as "tag dispatch" to deduce proper algorithm flavor.

For example, STL has a function "advance" which moves given iterator it by given n positions

```
template<class IteratorType,
    class IntegerDiffType> inline
    void advance(IteratorType& it, IntegerDiffType n)
```

For bidirectional iterators it has to apply ++ or -- many times; for random access iterators it can jump at once. This function is used in std::binary_search, std::lower_bound and some other algorithms.

Internally, it uses iterator type traits to select the strategy:

```
template<class IteratorType,
        class IntegerDiffType> 
        void advance(IteratorType& it, IntegerDiffType n)
{
    typedef typename iterator_traits<IteratorType>::category category;
    advance_impl(it, n, category());
}
```

Of course, STL has to implement the overloaded "impl" functions:

```
template<class IteratorType,
        class IntegerDiffType> 
        void advance(IteratorType& it, IntegerDiffType n, bidirectional_iterator_tag)
{   // increment iterator by offset, bidirectional iterators
for (; 0 < n; --n)
    ++it;
for (; n < 0; ++n)
    --it;
}

template<class IteratorType,
        class IntegerDiffType> 
        void advance(IteratorType& it, IntegerDiffType n, random_access_iterator_tag)
{   // increment iterator by offset, random-access iterators
    it += n;
}
```